# List with different data types

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists like this

```
[ [[1, 2.1234], 3], [[2, 3], 4]]
```

and I'm trying to convert it to this:

```
[ [1, 2.1234, 3], [2, 3, 4] ]
```

I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will the inner lists *always* follow that nesting pattern? If so, you could then just do: `[[*sub, x] for sub, x in data]`

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work with floats?

Comment: what doesnt work? For the list you posted above, it produces the output you expet

Comment: It works on the example data. If you have an example that fails it would be helpful to see it so a new answer could be developed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga a more robust solution might be `[flatten(x) for x in data]` using the definition of `flatten` from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/5987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
main_list = [[[1, 2.1234], 3], [[2, 3], 4]]
main_flat = []

for i in main_list:
  sublist = []
  for j in i:
    if type(j) == list:
      sublist += j
    else:
      sublist.append(j)

  main_flat.append(sublist)
```

I think it will work for all types.